# Turn upper case to lowercase, lowercase to upper, add +5 to all numbers modulo 10

Tags: python

I need to turn uppercase to lowercase, lowercase to uppercase and I need to add each number +5 modulo 10. It doesn't work so could you please help me?
The sentence is "Hello World, 521" and the output should be "hELLO wORLD, 076". I need to use a function definition.

I tried this:

```
def fc1 (string):
    if string.upper == True:
        return string.lower
    else:
        return string.upper
    if string.isdigit == True:
        return ((string + 5 ) % 10)


fc1 ("Hello World, 521")
```

Answer (score 2):

use `str.swapcase`

```
''.join(str((int(i)+5)%10) if i.isdigit() else i.swapcase() for i in 'hello world 521')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to do this a little bit differently. I used "Hello World, 521", but in Czech, because I need it in Czech. I can't use i.swapcase because I didn't learn it yet.

```
    def fce1 (string):
       for i in (string):
          if i.isupper():
             print (i.lower(), end="")
          elif i.islower():
             print (i.upper(), end="")
          elif i.isdigit():
             print ((int(i)+5)%10, end="")
          else:
             print (i, end="")

fce1 ("Ahoj Světe, 521")
```

Output:

```
aHOJ sVĚTE, 076
```